# How to add an attribution on a GeoJSON Layer from Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, fields-attributes

I need to use a GeoJSON Layer on my Leaflet map. Here is a sample of my code:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
}

myGeoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
myGeoJsonLayer.addTo(map);                         
TOC.addOverlay(myGeoJsonLayer, "My GeoJSON Layer");
```

All is working.

Now I'd like to add an attribution on my layer but how?

Comment: I've had a response [here][1]. I've tried and it's working fine.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664516/leaflet-how-to-add-an-attribution-on-a-geojson-layer

Comment: could you please mark the question as answered? ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer )

Answer (score 4):

Copied from the answer on Stack Overflow here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664516/leaflet-how-to-add-an-attribution-on-a-geojson-layer

Quote:

> By default this isn't supported, but you can tack a getAttribution() method on an instance like so: http://bl.ocks.org/tmcw/05c7d1164a9e62e67e6d

The example js code provided is:

```
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidG1jdyIsImEiOiJIZmRUQjRBIn0.lRARalfaGHnPdRcc-7QZYQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio').setView([40, -74.50], 9);
var gj = L.geoJson();
gj.getAttribution = function() { return 'foo bar'; };
gj.addTo(map);
</script>
```